# Custom Java events with listeners vs. a JMS based implementation?

Tags: java, event-handling, jms

My application requires events to be fired based on some specific activities that happen.  I'm trying to determine if I should create my own event handling system using the Java EventObject with custom listeners similar to Java AWT Or should I use a JMS implementation?  I was considering either apache's Qpid or ActiveMQ solution.  I'm exploring these options at the moment and was wondering if anyone has experience with Qpid or ActiveMQ and can offer some advise (e.g., pros, cons to consider, etc)  Also, if anyone has any suggestions for building a simple event handling system... if it's even worth while to consider this over a JMS based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple event listeners (as used in Java AWT) require that events are handled immediately, within the same virtual machine, and typically within the same thread.

JMS (for instance using ActiveMQ) allows events to be handled at a later time (optionally buffering messages in persistent storage), and in other virtual machines / threads. That flexibility comes at the price of additional complexity and lower efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say much about your application but if you need a simple event handling system for a single virtual machine, have a look at [EventBus](http://www.eventbus.org/).

Answer (score 1):

**2016 Update**

Altho java events were added back in 2006, and this question is from 2010, these are still somehow "hidden" features in the Java API, reading the question I believe an alternative that does exactly what you want are Java events, but not the ones in AWT Java 6 events, that allows you to decouple your project modules and have JML like capabilities without a server, the only downside of the events compared to JMS, is that the listener must be running, or else the message will be lost into oblivion.

from: https://dzone.com/articles/java-ee6-events-lightweight

Yo create a message:

```
public class LogMessage implements Serializable {

    private final String message;
    private final Level level;

    LogMessage(String message, Level level) {
        this.message = message;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public Level getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
}
```

You create a producer:

```
@Inject Event<LogMessage> event;


event.fire(new LogMessage("Log it baby!", Level.INFO));
```

and finally, you create a consumer:

```
public class LogListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
    public void process(@Observes LogMessage message){
        LOGGER.log(message.getLevel(), message.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Check out the @Observes annotation.

All this is done synchronously and well to be more jms/like you want to make this process in asynchronous fashion, for this just add:

```
@Stateless
@Asynchronous
public class LogListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
    public void process(@Observes LogMessage message){
        LOGGER.log(message.getLevel(), message.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want any yet-to-be-processed messages/events to be persisted in case your JVM instance dies? If so, you'll want an external message queue. Will any other applications ever need to publish / consume the same messages as this application? Same thing.